# Can an MySQL Server communicate with outside?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming I have a MySQL CLI and I write something like

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (...);
```

Is the MySQL Server able to communicate with external ressources (ex: webservice) and make a HTTP Request (http://example.com/rowinserted) with data **each time** I insert a row.

For the moment, I have a script that checks every second if a row have been inserted.

Is there a documentation about this, I did not found anything related to this during my search.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. The database needs to be consistent, that means it will lock the table while your process is running.

E.g. you insert a row and it must respond to you "1 row inserted". Now imagine it takes time to call some external web source, which probably returns a timeout. So you wait for 1-row-insert like 5 seconds.

Now imagine you insert 100 rows. 1000 rows. Etc.

The worst thing happens to others (if database is concurrent): they also wait until you make all these requests, because they have restrictions in changing this table as long as your changes are not `commit`ed yet.

It is just a database, it stores data, you can simply do that in ANY programming language outside of the DB.

Comment: no. also not all locks are table level locks but its irrelevant, mysql cannot do what you are asking.